# Windows Mobile Calendar Integration

Tags: windows-mobile, integration

Is there any way to add events to the default calendar application on WM from my own WM application?

I use Windows Mobile 6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use the [Pocket Outlook Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.appointment.aspx) to create calendar appointments

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158751.aspx) is a sample that adds birthdays as calendar entries from your contacts.